# css background image before and after h1 tag

Tags: css

I have to style all h1 tags to have an image before and after h1 text.

I know how to add image before, but do not know how to add both.

CSS (styling h1 to have image before text)

```
h1 {
        background-image: url('images/h_ltr.png');
        background-position: left center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #5d5d5d;
    }
```

Comment: Multiple background images (CSS 3), or generated content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` css selectors.

```css
h1:before {
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0 20px;
    content: " ";
}
h1:after {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0 20px;
    content: " ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Comment: Do not understand how this work. I have tried it doesņt work.

Comment: You can't post a link to localhost, that's just on your computer. See this fiddle for example use: http://jsfiddle.net/tH2Lp/1

Comment: I see your fiddle, I have tried it with my webpage but it is not working as I want. I need h1 to be in the center of page, left image should start on the left border of content and right image should start on the right border of content. Currently no right image appears at all and left image is too far to the right. http://aussie-outdoordirect.com.au/import/sub/index.php?p=about_us

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work the same as in my example. The problem seems to be related to the empty space in the content. You can fix this by changing the `content` line to this: `content: "\00a0";`. The `\00a0` represents a blank character.

Comment: Now it seems to work. But one more question: how this padding:0 20px works? My images are 317px in width, I have added padding: 0 200px; currently on my webpage. If I add more it doesn't work.

Comment: that's a shorthand version of `padding: 0 20px 0 20px` so essentially you're getting 40px of padding with `padding: 0 20px`. If you need it to be more weighted on either the left or the right, you should use the long version.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use multiple background images. In this example, I set background images for the left, centre and right bg images:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    background-image: url("images/heading-bg-left.png"), url("images/heading-bg-right.png"), url("images/heading-bg-center.png"); /* set each bg image */
    background-position: left center, center center, right center; /* set position of each bg image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat-x; /* set repeat of each bg image */
    padding: 0 92px; /* 92px is the width of my left and right bg images */
    height: 120px; /* 120px is the height of each bg image */
    line-height: 120px; /* ditto */
}
```

The code is fairly self-explanatory, but basically I have used three `background-image`s with three `background-position`s and three `background-repeat`s.

Note that the image are rendered in reverse order. So, in my example, the left and right images will be drawn on top of the centre image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.container{
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
h1{
    font-size:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 40px;
}
h1:after{
    height:1px;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    background:green;
    top:10px;
    width:500%;
    right:-500%;
}
h1:before{
    height:1px;
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    background:red;
    top:10px;
    width:500%;
    left:-500%;
}


</style>

<div class="container">
     <h1>1</h1>
</div>
```